# Exception in thread java command error on termux

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, termux, bitcoinj

Hello Please help me to solve the error command in `termux` when running a java program an error like this occurs when running a java program

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bitcoinj/core/ECKey at btc.btc2.btc.main(btc.java:28) ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bitcoinj.core.ECKey at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 6 more
```

Please tell me what causes it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

org.bitcoinj.core.ECKey is not available at runtime

Comment: How do I fix it and what should I do